# How to get records between two latitudes and longitudes using Laravel, php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-maps, eloquent

[image]

here what I tried to get but it returns empty between 2 given coordinates

```
function searchListings(){
    $query = Listings::query();
    $sw_lat = request('sw_lat');
    $ne_lat = request('ne_lat');
    $sw_lng = request('sw_lng');
    $ne_lng= request('ne_lng');
    $query->whereBetween('latitude', [$sw_lat, $ne_lat])->whereBetween('longitude', [$sw_lng, $ne_lng]);
    return $query::paginate(5);
 }
```

Comment: Query looks good, are you sure you have numeric values in $sw_lat and the other variables?

Comment: Here are the values which i got from map bounds.

sw_lat = 26.972349273701543 , sw_lng = -133.93988937939454, ne_lat = 46.31001232283324,ne_lng = -86.54143662060547

Comment: Do you have numeric data type on latitude/longitude columns?

Comment: No,for these columns i have varchar

Comment: Yes this seems the issue. If you can post the answer so I can accept and that will help other guys too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Check datatype

Use a numeric database column type. Example of errors with a text/varchar column:

```
User::truncate();
User::factory()->count(1)->create(['name' => 1.5]);
User::whereBetween('name', [1,2])->paginate()->first();
// One result

User::truncate();
User::factory()->count(1)->create(['name' => -1.5]);
User::whereBetween('name', [-2,-1])->paginate()->first()
// No results (!)
```